# What are the seeback specs for common production peltier elements

Tags: peltier

I been hunting for weeks for the seeback output for the most commonly sold peltier elements. I found one set of specs for the TEC1 - 12704 branded by HP

rated at 49mv 11ma per degree of temperture differential.

But I can"t find anything for 12706 and above to 12715. I have read 3 dozen datasheets but none contain info on seeback effect output

12706 seems to be the most commonly sold peltier

Comment: Does searching for *Seeb**e**ck* help?

Comment: @Janka How do you get bold text in comments? Italic is done with underscore.

Comment: __Double Underscore__ (or double star)

Comment: i have searched for seeback and gotten only hits from youtube of people doing some minor testing.. Then I tried to narrow down but to this site and others giving me nothing but the same no data on the product. deep google only copies of data sheets I've read already

Comment: and nope using capitalization does not help in the search

Comment: Tried Seeback seebach seebeck long ago google and duck duck go same results